# Session variables in session wont persist

Tags: php

I am working on creating a session that needs to carry several variables over to new pages. However, when I set anything equal to a `$_SESSION` variable, it refuses to carry over to the new page and echo out. My page view counter continues to keep count of the number of refreshes or pages viewed.

```
<?php
session_name('work');
session_start();
$probt1 = 'probt1'; 
$_SESSION[probt3] = 'probt3';
$_SESSION['firstname'] = 'probt2';

if(isset($_SESSION['views']))
    $_SESSION['views']=$_SESSION['views']+1;
else
    $_SESSION['views']=1;
echo "Views=". $_SESSION['views'];
?>
```

The second page is here. This is where I am trying to echo out some of the variables from the code above.

```
<?php
session_name('work');
session_start();
$probt4 = 'probt4';
$_SESSION['firstname'];
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root" , "******" , "******" );
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
if(isset($_SESSION['views']))
    $_SESSION['views']=$_SESSION['views']+1;
else
    $_SESSION['views']=1;
echo "Views=". $_SESSION['views'];

echo '<br/>'.$_SESSION['firstname'].'hello this is where stuff is echoed out'.     $probt1.   $_SESSION[probt3].$probt4;

?>
```

So if anyone can give me any help or see what is wrong, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: In the first file, `$_SESSION[probt3]` may throw a warning (should use `$_SESSION['probt3']` instead), and in the second file, I'm not sure if you intended to do something with `$_SESSION['firstname']` on the fifth line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is a all messed up..

```
$_SESSION[probt3] = 'probt3';
```

should be (raises notice)

```
$_SESSION['probt3'] = 'probt3';
```

---

This line does nothing

```
$_SESSION['firstname'];
```

---

```
echo '<br/>'.$_SESSION['firstname'].'hello this is where stuff is echoed out'.$probt1.   $_SESSION[probt3].$probt4;
```

`$probt1` is not defined, `$_SESSION[probt3]` same as above

---

Apart from that the code runs as it should... what exactly is your problem?

Here's the corrected code I tested

FILE1.php

```
//Global variable doesn't carry to the other page
$probt1 = 'probt1'; 

//Session variables do
$_SESSION['probt3'] = 'probt3';
$_SESSION['firstname'] = 'probt2';
$_SESSION['views'] = (isset($_SESSION['views'])) ? ++$_SESSION['views'] : $_SESSION['views'];

echo "Views = " . $_SESSION['views'];
```

FILE2.php

```
<?php
session_name('work');
session_start();

$probt4 = 'probt4';

$_SESSION['firstname']; // This line isn't doing anything

$_SESSION['views'] = (isset($_SESSION['views'])) ? ++$_SESSION['views'] : $_SESSION['views'];

echo "Views=". $_SESSION['views'];

var_dump($_SESSION);
```

Comment: thanks I know some of the code was messed up I had it in there to try and help problem solve. The problem was it wouldn't echo anything from the previous page I couldn't figure out why and eventually just re wrote everything with your suggestions and it worked so thanks!

Comment: no prob mate. Glad I could be of help